# Is it possible to query just Solana transactions?

Tags: jsonrpc-api

Since Solana is a native token it doesn't have an associated account. So I'm failing to find a good way to query only Solana transaction (transactions that changed Solana balance)

Comment: the system program for transfer is a program and you can listen on it's transactions, have you considered that?

Comment: Thanks Frank. But I'd love to query historical data.